# Order when combining @mock.patch on class and methods

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

When a method should be mocked within a test case it is possible to apply the `@mock.patch` decorator in the python `unittest` framework (see [1](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#patch-decorators)):

```
    class MyTest(TestCase):
        @patch('method2')
        @patch('method1')
        def test_stuff(self, mock_method1, mock_method_2):
            ...
```

According to the docs [2](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#applying-the-same-patch-to-every-test-method), it is also possible to apply the `@mock.patch` as a class decorator:

```
    @patch('method2')
    @patch('method1')
    class MyTest(TestCase):
        def test_stuff(self, mock_method_1, mock_method_2):
            ...
```

So it should also be possible and reasonable to combine these two approaches:

```
    @patch('method1')
    class MyTest(TestCase):
        @patch('method2')
        def test_stuff(self, mock_method_A, mock_method_B):
            ...
```

Now I was wondering in which order the mocks are passed to `test_stuff`.
So does `mock_method_A` mock `method1` or `method2`?

Answer (score 7):

The mocks from the method decorator are applied before the class decorator. I.e
`mock_method_A` is the mock for `method2` and `mock_method_B` is the mock for `method1`

See this self contained example for illustration:

```
from unittest import TestCase, main, mock


def method1():
    return 1


def method2():
    return 2


@mock.patch('test.method2', return_value='method2')
@mock.patch('test.method1', return_value='method1')
class TestClassDecoratorOrder(TestCase):
    def test_order(self, mock_method1, mock_method2):
        self.assertEqual(mock_method1(), 'method1')
        self.assertEqual(mock_method2(), 'method2')


class TestMethodDecoratorOrder(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('test.method2', return_value='method2')
    @mock.patch('test.method1', return_value='method1')
    def test_order(self, mock_method1, mock_method2):
        self.assertEqual(mock_method1(), 'method1')
        self.assertEqual(mock_method2(), 'method2')


@mock.patch('test.method2', return_value='method2')
class TestCombinedDecoratorOrder(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('test.method1', return_value='method1')
    def test_order(self, mock_method1, mock_method2):
        self.assertEqual(mock_method1(), 'method1')
        self.assertEqual(mock_method2(), 'method2')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```